# How do I get the pointerdown event to work on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, addeventlistener

I am unable to get pointerdown events to fire on Firefox (55), but the same works fine on Chrome (60), e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click or tap anywhere in the document.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("pointerdown", function() {
        console.log("pointerdown fired");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Hello World! ";
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox, using a mouse or a touch device the pointerdown event is not fired. In Chrome the same thing works fine.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmLr31c3/3/).

Comment: try `mousedown` instead of `pointerdown`

Comment: I do not want to use mousedown as I want a generic event to work on both touch and desktop devices. pointerdown was created for this purpose, so you don't have to register mousedown and touchstart etc, but instead a single event.

Comment: you are right but many numbers of the browser do not support the event.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointerdown see the supporting.And also refer General info of the pointer

Comment: That's fine because we are only targeting Windows desktop and Firefox and Chrome (because our application requires WebRTC with data channel support). We don't need full support across all platforms, but Firefox is listed as having support for these events on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like pointer events are not enabled by default in Firefox anymore. See [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=960316) on Bugzilla for details.
To turn on pointer events, navigate to **about:config**, search for **dom.w3c_pointer_events.enabled** and then right click to toggle the value to **true**.